# Template Can Only Access Last Element of Controller Array Property in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller on which I've defined an array property:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  predModels: [
    Ember.Object.create {name: 'position', check: true},
    Ember.Object.create {name: 'lfpTimesPosition', check: true},
    Ember.Object.create {name: 'lfp', check: true}
  ]
```

I have not defined any route. When I iterate in the application template, only the last item in the array is accessible. The array appears to have a length of 1. For testing purposes, I have set my entire application template to the below (written in Emblem). Only one `h5 itemhere` is created.

```
div
  each predModels
    h5 itemhere
```

When I create a [very simple JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2505/edit?html,js,output) in which the app consists almost purely of something like this, I don't have the same problem; .  What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is calling `Ember.Object.create` without putting parentheses around the arguments. It seems only one object is being created at the top level and the others are being passed as arguments to the `create()` function of the first.